# How to create pivot table based on data in a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, pygsheets

Lets say I have data in Google Sheets as below:

```
   A   B   C
0  a  33  13
1  b  44  14
2  a  55  15
3  a  66  16
4  b  77  17
5  c  88  18
```

As stated in the title, is there any way to create a pivot table with pygsheets?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I can see with version 2.0.3 of [pygsheets](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets), the current functionality does not exist.

Many of pygsheets functions use the [batchUpdate method from the Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) to update and manipulate data but, as far as I can see there are no references to the [Pivot Table code from the Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/pivot-tables#PivotTable) in the pygsheets project files.

You can find more about [adding pivot tables and the Google Sheets API in the documentation from Google.](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/pivot-tables)